# Update data using jQuery and Ajax

Tags: asp.net

I am new to ASP.NET and building a financial web application. I have a form with a code behind file. On my form I have 5 text boxes which populates on PageLoad event and user can modify the field values and update in database so therefore I have a button called "Update Details". I dont want to POSTBACK instead I want user to click on UPDATE Details and stay there.

My question is that can I utilize my code behind file and write a function there for example "Proc_UpdateProfile" and execute the procedure using $(ajax) of jquery or what will be the excelent method in terms of fast, reliable and top performance.

Do you think that calling dummy web service and a WebMethod using AJAX can achieve my goal?

Any other ideas would highly be appreciated with example.

Thanks

Comment: I know this will sound arrogant and condescending, but if you're new to ASP.NET should you really be building a financial application?

Comment: roryf I have been programming since 1994 and started my career with dbase III+ and have oracle programming background and done some projects in Visual Basic. I have made one small application in asp.net but it was with code behind only now i want to come up with some spicy stuff (AJAX) so thats why i asked. And I think one should get their hands dirty with any new thing and should start building financial application to learn fast and also learn to deal with common programming problems.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use PageMethods - see http://encosia.com/2008/05/29/using-jquery-to-directly-call-aspnet-ajax-page-methods/

If you want to make Proc_UpdateProfile a more general function to be called from elsewhere (other than this one page), then you could create a web service which would work in a similar way

Comment: Well thanks for your suggestions..i want to create a one global service and wherever I need AJAX calls I would call the service and invoke the WebMethod. So should I simply go to Solutions Explorer ->Add New Item->Select WebService ??

And call using jquery script via $(ajax) 
contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8" ??

Comment: In that case, do a Google search on 'call asmx web service from jquery' - should be plenty of tutorials/examples there. Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

you can use an update panel. If you are into JQuery look into BlockUI but there is a validation thing you have to figure out. Good luck.
http://encosia.com/2008/10/04/using-jquery-to-enhance-aspnet-ajax-progress-indication/

Answer (score 0):

For Financial application your data must be secured, so server side processing would be more secure....

As it is a Profile update calling an asp.NET method would be preferred via jQuery Ajax.